# How to reduce a matrix rank using some zeros?

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, reduce, rank

I'm working of matrices having rank >1. It is possible to reduce the rank of a matrix to rank=1 substituing some values to zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at the **singular value decomposition**, which can be used to write your matrix as a sum of weighted outer products (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition#Low-rank_matrix_approximation)). Choosing only the highest-weighted component of this sum will give you the closest rank-1 approximation to the decomposed matrix.

Most common linear algebra libraries ([Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1JacobiSVD.html), [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/df/df7/classcv_1_1SVD.html), [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html)) have an SVD implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Rank in a matrix refers to how many of the column vectors are independent and non-zero (Or row vectors, but I was taught to always use column vectors). So, if you're willing to lose a lot of the information about the transformation your matrix is defining, you could create a matrix that's just the first non-zero column of your matrix, and everything else set to zero. Guaranteed to be rank 1.

However, that loses a whole lot of information about the transformation. Perhaps a more useful thing to do would be project your matrix onto a space of size 1x1. There are ways to do this in such a way that can create an injection from your matrix to the new space, guaranteeing that no two matrices produce an equivalent result. The first one that comes to mind is:
`Let A be an n x m matrix
Let {P_i} be the ith prime number.
Let F(A) = {sum from i to (n * m)} {P_i} ^ (A_(i div n),(i mod m))`

While this generates a single number, you can think of a single number as a 1 x 1 matrix, which, if non-zero, has rank 1.

All that being said, rank 1 matrices are kinda boring and you can do cooler stuff with matrices if you keep it at rank != 1. In particular, if you have an n x n matrix with rank n, a whole world of possibility opens up. It really depends on what you want to use these matrices for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respose. These matrices are kernels (image filters) and i want to convolve them to a image. I know that if rank=1 a matrix is separable and it allows me to implement a faster convolution. My filters are made by small values (10^-3), so if I can apply a smart flooring on that filters in a way to make them separable could be nice.